# vim youcompleteme cannot auto-complete self-defined python module

Tags: python, vim, youcompleteme

I using [youcommpleteme](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) to auto-complete assist writing python code. And I find that the build-in modules such as `os` or `simplejson` will work like charm.

But if I wrote some modules myself and after importing the modules auto-completion will not work. For instance, if I have a dir structure like this:

```
├── utils
│   ├── DBCUtils.py
│   ├── DBCUtils.pyc
│   ├── email.conf
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── log.py
│   ├── mail.py
│   ├── mail.pyc
│   ├── mysql.conf
│   ├── mysqlorm.py
│   ├── mysqlorm.pyc
│   ├── propertyutils.py
├──test.py
```

And if import mysqlorm.py in test.py:

```
from utils.mysqlorm import *

session = getSession()
```

this `getSession()` which was defined in `utils.mysqlorm` will not be auto-completed, but if I wrote:

```
import simplejson as json
json.dumps(dic, indent=4, ensure_asscii=False)
```

And this will be auto-completed.

And I also find that if I open the `mysqlorm.py` in the same vim session, all method defined in the file will got auto-completion, but I don't want to bother opening every file I imported.

So is there a way I can got auto-completion helper for granted(without opening it first)?

Answer (score 0):

YouCompleteMe uses Jedi.

Jedi is based on the buffer vim and sys.path for autocompletion.
To avoid having to open the python files, add them to sys.path.

For this, you can create a script in .vim/after/ftplugin/my_script.vim

In this script, add your currentpath to sys.path.

For example:

```
python << EOF
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
EOF
```

Attention, getcwd returns where you open vim.

And if you are using a buildout, you can use this script: https://github.com/FBruynbroeck/vim-buildout